# Character extraction in R?

Tags: r

How would I extract 'mpg' from the following formula in R? I understand that it would be useful to convert the formula into character first and then use some kind of regex. But I don't know which one.

```
mpg ~ x1 + x2
```

Answer (score 5):

We can use `all.vars`

```
all.vars(form)[1]
#[1] "mpg"
```

Or with `terms`

```
as.character(attr(terms(form), "variables")[[2]])
#[1] "mpg"
```

Or another option is

```
paste(form)[[2]]
#[1] "mpg"
```

where

```
form <-  mpg ~ x1 + x2
```

Comment: If you are doing `as.character`, how about `as.character(form)[2]`

Answer (score 3):

Here's an approach that uses regex

```
x = mpg ~ x1 + x2
gsub(" ","",gsub("~.*", "", deparse(x)))
#[1] "mpg"
```

Comment: I think the `Reduce` call may be redundant.  As far as I can tell, this works equally as well using just `gsub(" ","",sub("~.*", "", deparse(x)))`

Answer (score 3):

All of the given answers will work for your specific use case.  But if you wish to use this in a more generalized sense, there are some caveats to be aware of. To discuss these, we'll define a few formulae

```
fm <- mpg ~ x1 + x2
fm_one <- ~ x1 + x2
fm_multi <- mpg + y1 ~ x1 + x2
```

`all.vars` will return a character vector of all of the variables in the formula. It is the fastest of the options given to this point. However, it does *not* distinguish between variables on the left hand and right hand side of the equation. Whether or not this is acceptable depends on your use case.

```
all.vars(fm)[1]         # "mpg"
all.vars(fm_one)[1]     # "x1" (this is a right hand side variable)
all.vars(fm_multi)[1]   # "mpg"  (missing other left hand side variables)
```

The `terms` approach (`as.character(attr(terms(fm), "variables"))`) will generate a similar vector, but the variable names start in the second position (the `list` call takes up the first element). It suffers the same disadvantages as the `all.vars` approach.

```
as.character(attr(terms(fm), "variables"))[2]        # "mpg"
as.character(attr(terms(fm_one), "variables"))[2]    # "x1"
as.character(attr(terms(fm_multi), "variables"))[2]  # "mpg"
```

Using `as.character` produces a character vector of either length 3 or 2, depending on if there is or isn't a left hand side.  This at least has the ability to return the entire left side, but it won't return a character vector of the response variables. It still has the disadvantage, however, of not being distinguishing left sides variables from right side variables.

```
as.character(fm)        # "~" "mpg" "x1" "x2"
as.character(fm_one)    # "~" "x1" "x2"
as.character(fm_multi)  # "~" "mpg" "y1" "x1" "x2"
```

The `deparse` method is somewhat slower than `all.vars` (but still measured in nanoseconds), and has the primary advantage of distinguishing left hand side from right hand side.

```
gsub(" ","",gsub("~.*", "", deparse(fm)))        # "mpg"
gsub(" ","",gsub("~.*", "", deparse(fm_one)))    # ""
gsub(" ","",gsub("~.*", "", deparse(fm_multi)))  # "mpg+y1"
```

Depending on your actual needs, you may not need to protect against one-sided or multivariate formulae.  If you are working in a system where it is known that all of your formulae will be univariate and two sided, `all.vars` is probably your best bet.  If you can't be sure of that, I'd recommend using the `deparse` method.  That will at least ensure that you always get response variables when you are looking for response variables.

Answer (score 2):

Given the formula:

```
frm <- as.formula(mpg ~ x1 + x2)
```

it is possible to extract the term on the left side simply using:

```
as.character(frm[[2]])
[1] "mpg"
```